# Read from a text file and then decide wether we want to disable or enable a button in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
     $filename ="E:\\Serialportread\\boxcheck.txt";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
if($data=="CLOSED")
{
echo'<td><button id="read" class="bott2" style="margin-top:18px;">Read</button></td><td>';
}
else{
echo'<td><button id="read" class="bott2" style="margin-top:18px;" disabled="disabled">Read</button></td><td>';
}
```

this happening before click.

code below is on click function defined :

```
$('#read').click(function(e){
    var fso1, ForReading;
    ForReading = 1;var status;
    fso1 = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    file = fso1.OpenTextFile("E:\\Serialportread\\boxcheck.txt", ForReading, false, -2);
    status = file.ReadLine();
    file.Close();
    alert(status);
    if(status=='CLOSED')
    {
      alert('ysess');
      $.fn.a();
      e.preventDefault();
      }
      else{
      alert('error')
    $('#read').html('');
      str='<diasabled="disabled">';
      $('#read').append(str);
    alert('yes');


      }
    });
```

Both the codes are not working.
I tried another code as well but that was refreshing my page again and again which i don't want .

Comment: uh..which code do you want to use? the PHP one or JS? they both are doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: Any code will work....I just want the purpose to be solved.

Comment: are you getting perfect output in jquery ??? if yes then you just need little change in jquery

Comment: Yes output is right but it refresh my page,which I dont want.

Comment: If you make your JS code working, the ActiveX will access client's file system. If you make your PHP code working, it will access server's file system. I hope you understand the differences in both. Specify clear purpose of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in

```
str='<diasabled="disabled">';
```

di**A**sabled

You should better try not to mess with the HTML - use style instead:

```
if(status=='CLOSED')
{
  alert('ysess');
  var cb = $("#read");
  cb.removeAttribute("disabled");
  removeClass(cb, "button-disabled"); 
}
else
{
  alert('error')
  var cb = $('#read');
  // visually change the button - otherwise it does not look as disabled
  addClass(cb, "button-disabled"); 
  cb.setAttribute("disabled","");
  alert('yes');
}
```